# Python checking for empty list on a Path subclass is returning 'AttributeError' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Here's my subclass of Path that takes a recursive os.walk(), and maps it to my custom path.

Important to note, there's a bug in this code where dirs and files are not being passed correctly.

However, my question is: given this bug, and the missing dirs/files properties, even though I've given both attributes a default value in `init`, it actually throws an `AttributeError` error when I try to reference `self.dirs` or `self.files`, stating

```
AttributeError: 'WalkPath' object has no attribute 'dirs'
```

What's going on? Why isn't it taking my default values?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union

class WalkPath(type(pathlib.Path())):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(WalkPath, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, dirs: []=[], files: []=[]):
        """Initialize WalkPath object.

        Args:
            dirs (list):        Dirs provided by os.walk(), defauls to []
                                         
            files (list):       Files provided by os.walk(), defaults to []
        """
        
        super().__init__()
        self.dirs: [WalkPath] = [WalkPath(d) for d in dirs]
        self.files: [WalkPath] = [WalkPath(f) for f in files]
    
    @property
    def is_terminus(self):
        return self.is_file() or not self.dirs
    
    @property
    def dirs_abs(self):
        return [self.joinpath(d) for d in self.dirs]
    
    @property
    def files_abs(self):
        return [self.joinpath(f) for f in self.files]
        
    class Utils:

        @staticmethod
        def find_deep(path: Union[str, Path, 'WalkPath']) -> ['WalkPath']:
            """Deeply search the specified dir and return all files and subdirs.
            If path passed is a file, return a list with that single file.

            Args:
                path (str or Path): Root path to search for files.
                
            Returns:
                A filtered list of files or an empty list.
            """

            _path = WalkPath(path) # Coerce to WalkPath
            # print(_path)
            
            if _path.is_file():
                return [_path]

            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                wp = WalkPath(root, dirs=dirs, files=files)
                for d in wp.dirs_abs:
                    yield d
                    WalkPath.Utils.find_deep(d)

                for f in wp.files_abs:
                    yield WalkPath(f)

paths = WalkPath.Utils.find_deep(Path('/tests/files').resolve())
paths = sorted(paths, key=lambda p: str(p).lower())

for p in paths:
    print(p.parent, p.dirs)
```

It's definitely the correct type, and was initialized correctly, because if I add:

```
@property
def test(self):
    return True
```

then:

```
print(all([p.test and type(p) is WalkPath for p in paths]))
# prints True
```

but no matter what, I can't access `self.dirs` or `self.files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you do this:

```
for d in wp.dirs_abs:
    yield d
```

dir_abs returns

```
return [self.joinpath(d) for d in self.dirs]
```

`self.joinpath` calls `Path.joinpath` which returns a `Path` object, not a `WalkPath` object.  It hasn't passed through your `__init__`.  You need to wrap that.

### Followup

OK, so this is a quirk in `pathlib`.  In the functions like `joinpath` where it has to create new objects, it's calling `__new__` but apparently not calling your `__init__`.  Instead, it calls a function called `_init`.  It's worth tracing through this in the source for pathlib.py.  If you add this to your WalkPath, it looks to me like it works:

```
def _init(self):
    super()._init()
    self.dirs: [WalkPath] = []
    self.files: [WalkPath] = []
```

### OP's solution

Overriding `joinpath` works as well, and setting `_flavour` directly eliminates the need to call `__new__`.

```
class WalkPath(Path):
    
    _flavour = type(Path())._flavour
    
    def __init__(self, *args, dirs: []=[], files: []=[]):
        super().__init__()
        self.dirs: [WalkPath] = [WalkPath(d) for d in dirs]
        self.files: [WalkPath] = [WalkPath(f) for f in files]
    
    def joinpath(self, path) -> 'WalkPath':
        joined = WalkPath(super().joinpath(path))
        self.__dict__ = joined.__dict__.copy()
        return joined
```

Comment: Try inserting `print(d.dirs)` between the `for d in wp.dirs_abs` and the `yield d`.  You'll see that I'm right.  The `d` object that you are returning is a Path.  How do you think that `Path.joinpath` can possibly return a `WalkPath`?

Comment: And your `__new__` handler is unnecessary and can be deleted.  Are you planning something more for that?

Comment: I'm not sure my second suggestion works, either.  The final output doesn't seem to have any files.  You may have to provide a custom implementation of `joinpath`.

Comment: I did get it working! Your initial answer was correct, but the way I ended up solving it was by overriding joinpath. If you're cool with it, I'll edit your answer to include that solution, then accept it.

Comment: That's just fine.